# Resolving promise value in Html -> Ctrl -> Factory -> Resource chain on deferred object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

In `edit.html`

```
<div>timezone: {{userPreferencesCtrl.preference.response.format}}<div>
```

In `UserPreferencesCtrl`

```
 this.preference = UserPreferencesFactory.userPreference;
```

In `UserPreferencesFactory`

Basically there are two rest-calls. 
Fist - gets all user-preferences and on its success it call another rest-call - getting particular user-preference.

```
var factory = this;

factory.userPreference = $q.defer();
...    
UserPreferencesResource.all().$promise.then(          
     function(data) {
       // some code
       if (foundRightGuy) {             
          // get preference by ID
          UserPreferencesResource.get( {id: pref.preferenceID}).$promise.then(
            function(data) {
               factory.userPreference.resolve(data); // resolving the promise
             }
          );
        }
     }
 );

return this;     }]);
```

The problem is that on the Controller side I see the resolved promise like this:

```
{"promise":{"$$state":{"status":1,"value":{"response":{"preferenceID":2,"user_name":"name3", "format":"keyvalue"}}}}}
```

Which does not rendered on the edit.html.

How to make it show `preference.response.format` value on the screen?

UPDATE: (angularjs 1.3.x)

If instead of `$q.defer();` I put  `UserPreferencesResource.get( {id: 2})` call - then all renders well. Just saying that all variables are good (no misspelling or something).

Comment: did you try the code in my answer? the deffered object's property is promise without $.

Comment: just tried. updated my update.

Comment: you're still not unwraping the promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get when you call `UserPreferencesFactory.userPreference` is the deffered object, which has the promise as a property. So you have to unwrap that promise.

Controller:

```
this.preference;

UserPreferencesFactory
   .userPreference
   .promise
   .then(function(data) {
     this.preference = data;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to connect data in `Ctr -> Factory -> Resource` chain is this:

In `UserPreferencesCtrl`

```
this.preference = UserPreferencesFactory.userPreference
```

So no need to referencing `promise` or doing `then`. That is quite manual way of doing this.

Then in `Factory` NO need to do any `$q.defer` or `$q.resolve` either. But instead this may be as simple as this:

```
 factory.userPreference = {} // default value
 UserPreferencesResource.all().then(function(data) {
   //... may be more calls if we need it
   angular.extend(factory.userPreference, data);  // that part is important
 })
```

`angular.extend` - copies data to exiting source - to `factory.userPreference`. And that makes Ctrl see the changes/updates. Otherwise doing assignment `factory.userPreference = data` would not let the change be visible for `Controller`

That's why before I tried to `resolve/reject` promise manually to avoid direct assignments - to let angular binding works between Controller and Factory. But `angular.extend` that seems much cleaner solution.

Otherwise, on top of boilerplate coding that manual way of doing things (for me) led to  problems with grunt when it evaluates all those 'open promises' like : `var promise = UserPreferenceFactory.userPreference.promise; + some other unexpected issues.`

So, do not hesitate to use `angular.extend` if you found yourself writing too many promises.. and updating the states this way. That was my advice to myself today.